# How to remove suffix from file in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, command

I found out that you can apparently add suffix on the fly, this is useful for me to disable a service that relies on the existence of file extension.

```
$ mv -v file.txt{,.bak}
renamed 'file.txt' -> 'file.txt.bak'
```

But how can one do the reverse ? What command I have to use ?

```
$ mv -v file.txt.bak{??}
renamed 'file.txt.bak' -> 'file.txt'
```

Comment: `file.txt{.bak,}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command (`mv -v file.txt{,.bak}`) relies on Bash brace expansion, which translates `file.txt{,.bak}` to `file.txt file.txt.bak`.  Check out the Bash manpage section for "Brace Expansion".  In this case (`{,.bak}`), there are two strings in the comma-separated list: an empty string and `.bak`.  As such, you can add extensions and the like.

Several examples come to mind for removing extensions using brace expansions (all expanding to `mv -iv file.txt.bak file.txt`):

- `mv -iv file.txt{.bak,}`
- `f=file.txt.bak; mv -iv ${f%.bak}{.bak,}`, which doesn't presuppose the filename preceding the ".bak" extension (in the Bash manpage, see "Remove matching suffix pattern")
- `f=file.txt.bak; mv -iv ${f%.*}{.${f##*.},}`, which doesn't presuppose any specific extension (in the Bash manpage, additionally see "Remove matching prefix pattern")

As an alternative, and as another contributor suggests, `rename` is a useful and powerful utility (e.g., `rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak`).

P.S.  Whenever documenting or scripting variabilized examples, I generally recommend quoting for whitespace safety (e.g., `mv -iv "${f%.*}"{."${f##*.}",}`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
file.txt{.bak,}
```

In this way you substitute the word before the comma with the empty string that is after the comma.

Comment: It will be expanded as `mv -v file.txt.bak.bak file.txt.bak`.

Answer (score 0):

why donot use `rename` command.

```
rename '.bak' '' fileNames
```